# Android, does layoutParams points on parent view and not the view itself?

Tags: android, android-view, layoutparams

I got a problem when trying to update dynamically the `layoutParams` of a view.

The view to update is a `ConstraintLayout`, and I want to dynamically change it's `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio` property.

The fragment XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LevelFragment">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/board"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

But when I try to change it from Kotlin fragment code

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    board = view.findViewById(R.id.board)
    // Set ratio
    val layoutParams = board!!.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
    layoutParams.dimensionRatio = "5:1"
    board!!.layoutParams = layoutParams
}
```

It fails with this error after debug build :

> android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams

So, I'm wondering why it complains about FrameLayout to ConstraintLayout cast, because the `layoutParams` is taken from the `board` View, which is a `ConstraintLayout`...

Does the paramsLayout refers to the parent view and not the view itself ?

And if so, how to update view `dimensionRatio` property ?

Thanks !

Comment: Layout params are provided by views parent, in this case `ConstraintLayout` is child of `FrameLayout` so the latter is responsible for laying it out.

Comment: @Pawel Ok, I can understand that ; but most of examples I found (Stackoverflow included) cast the layoutParams with the view type, and not the parent type.. How can I update the current view property ? FrameLayout doesn't have a "dimensionRatio" property :/

Comment: Also, update view.layoutParams seems to update the view and not the parent ?

Comment: Replace `FrameLayout` with another `ConstraintLayout` then you'll be able to use constraints. Even though params are held within the view they are parsed by its parent during layout cycle.

Comment: It's a brain broker.. So to update specific layout property, its parent has to be of the same type ? I cannot update specific ConstraintLayout property (which is applied on itself) because its parent is a FrameLayout..

Comment: Your `board` has `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` because it's a child of `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Okay ; does this mean that `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"` property on the ConstraintLayout (XML) has no effect on itself, because its parent is a FrameLayout ? Otherwise, if it's legit like it is, is there a way to update it without modifying XML ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LayoutParams` are the parameters which parent `ViewGroup` uses to layout its children. Each child has its own `LayoutParams` which has a specific type based on type of its parent. i.e. children of `FrameLayout` has `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` as their `LayoutParams` and children of `LinearLayout` has `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` as their `LayoutParams` and so on. Also they can not get cast to each other, it means you can not cast `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` to `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` since they have different implementation of `LayoutParams`. But all of `LayoutParams` have exteded `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`, so it is safe to cast them to `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`. 
In your case you are casting `board.layoutParams` to `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams` but since parent of `board` is a `FrameLayout` then its `LayoutParams` is of type `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` and can not get cast to `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams`. 
If you want to fix this you have to replace parent of `board` which is a `FrameLayout` with a `ConstraintLayout`.
Also you can read [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout) if you want to see how `LayoutParams` works.

Comment: Thanks, if I understand correctly, a layout can only hold params that its parent supports ? Disappointed that AndroidStudio didn't warn me when adding these properties on the XML side

Comment: Yes that is exactly how it works. And I do agree with you about the disappointment part since I also got lots of crashes because of casting layout parameters to a wrong type :D